# How to setup a fallback resource file for Views

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-localization

Using `IViewLocalizer` I would like to implement view localization with a default or fallback resource file for words and phrases that appear on multiple pages like for example edit, add, delete... I don't want to add these repetitive phrases in the resource file of all the views where they appear so a fallback recource file would really come handy, but I just can't seem to find any solutions on how to do that.

Currently I'm using `@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer` on my views and I'm getting the localized phrases with `@Localizer["ResourceName"]` from the resource files:

> Resources/Views/{ControllerName}/{ViewName}.{langCode}.resx

This works just fine for each separate view and partial view. Now I would like to have a resource file either in the `Resources/Views` or `Resources` folder that acts as a fallback resource file.

So for example if I say `@Localizer["Edit"]` on one of my views and the "Edit" resource is not found in the `Resources/Views/{ControllerName}/{ViewName}.{langCode}.resx` or `Resources/Views/{ControllerName}/{ViewName}.resx`, it falls back to this default file so that I can use this on all of my views that need the resource "Edit".

I've allready tried with `Resources/Resource.{langCode}.resx` but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: That's a good question. Try posting this question on the aspnet/MVC repo on GitHub

Comment: the default behavior in previous .NET frameworks/stacks was to have a resource file without a culture in it, i.e. `Resource.resx`. Also please note that when there is no suitable locale, the string put into `@Localizer["string"]` will be returned, which is also  used in the official samples iirc: Means: instead of message strings they suggest directly use the default string as "keys", i.e. `@Localizer["This is an default locale string"]` and override this via locale. Example: https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/dev/samples/LocalizationSample/Startup.cs#L74

Comment: I know about using the default string as the key, but that does not help me with localizing repetitive phrases at all! That is exactly what I don't want to do. I don't want to override the phrase in a locale for a specific view because it repeates in most of my views. I want a default resource file for all views where the reptitive phrases go, so I'm interested in the Resource.resx you mentioned. I would like a default resource.resx for each lanaguage.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Kiran Challa. I just did so.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar problem when I started with localization. If you have a lot of repeated phrases and words on your site it's best to put them in a SharedResource file.

You do it by creating a `SharedResource.[LANG_CODE].resx` file in `Resources` folder. Then you need to create a dummy class that you call `SharedResource` and put it in the root of your project namespace. So if your project is called `LocalizationTest` then the class would look something like that:

```
namespace LocalizationTest
{
    public class SharedResource
    {
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do to access shared resource in your model or view is to create a `IStringLocalizer<SharedResources>` and use it. Like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<HomeController> _localizer;
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> _sharedLocalizer;

    public HomeController(IStringLocalizer<HomeController> localizer,
                   IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> sharedLocalizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
        _sharedLocalizer = sharedLocalizer;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["message"] = _sharedLocalizer["Hello!"];
        return View();
    }
}
```

Or in a view:
    @inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
    @inject IStringLocalizer SharedLocalizer

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = SharedLocalizer["Hello!"];
}

<h1>@Localizer["Welcome message"]</h1>
```

I have skipped import and using statements for brevity.

You can find more info about SharedResource and general localization here: [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization) or in an answer to the question I posted here [My questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42649361/4185238).