# Globalization in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, globalization

I read articles about globalizing asp.net core application. All of them suggests to create 'Resources' folder and create sub folders and for each Controller/View/ViewModel, create resource file for each language. Is there a better way to do this, just having one resource file per language? If yes, what change I need to make in startup.cs file?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to do this, just having one resource file per language?

Globalization with help of SharedResource, you could refer to the below :

1. `SharedResource.cs` , put it in the **root folder of project** and it does not need to contain any data, just the class declaration.
2. create a resource file called the same as the .cs file and it needs to be put in the Resources folder.
   [image]

For the usage of SharedResource file , you could refer to below links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1

[ASP.NET Core Localization with help of SharedResources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647384/asp-net-core-localization-with-help-of-sharedresources/42649361#42649361)