# Blazor wasm localization showing just keys

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Followed [Dynamically set the culture from the Accept-Language header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly#dynamically-set-the-culture-from-the-accept-language-header) to localize my blazor wasm app.

WebUI.csproj

```
<BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

Added folder:

```
Resources
   Shared.resx
   Shared.en.resx
```

_Imports.razor

```
@using WebUI.Resources
```

In view:

```
@using System.Globalization
@inject IStringLocalizer<Shared> loc
@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
@loc["countries"]
```

Culture is showing DE-DE. @loc["countries"] just prints countries instead of the localization. Any ideas why?

Comment: If you are seeing the key and not the Localization, it means it can't find the files. Also, de-DE is not part of your Localized files, maybe it doesn't fall back to the default?

Comment: Give it a try as `builder.Services.AddLocalization();` without setting `ResourcesPath`.

Comment: @pfx that worked. Can you make this an answer and eleborate why this works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For (shared) resources, `Blazor` follows the same setup/rules as for `ASP.NET Core`.

In short, when you specify an `options.ResourcesPath`, its value is being added as a prefix to the name of your resource,
which by default is `namespace` + resource name.

With that `options.ResourcesPath` set to `Resources` you get `Resources.WebUI.Resources.Shared.resx` instead of `WebUI.Resources.Shared.resx`.

To solve, don't set a `ResourcesPath`, just use

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization();
```

[Link to ASP.NET Core question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647384/asp-net-core-localization-with-help-of-sharedresources)

Answer (score 0):

You only specified an English localization file: `Shared.en.resx`.

When you specify `@loc["countries"]` in the component, it attempts to use the browser locale to translate the text "countries".

The localizer looks for a resource file `Shared.de.resx` but that doesn't exist, so it defaults to the base translation, in this case English.